# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsFilename

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jar

I am trying to simply rename cloud storage file on app engine.

During the execution, it returns these errors:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsFilename at com.GAEApplication.GAEApplicationServlet.loadFile(GAEApplicationServlet.java:40)
        at com.GAEApplication.GAEApplicationServlet.moveFile(GAEApplicationServlet.java:33)
        at com.GAEApplication.GAEApplicationServlet.doGet(GAEApplicationServlet.java:28)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)**

The Error code lines are :

```
private byte[] loadFile(String bucket, String fileName) throws IOException {

        GcsFilename gcsFileName = new GcsFilename(bucket, fileName);
         GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
            GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openReadChannel(gcsFileName, 0);
            InputStream in = newInputStream(readChannel);
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
```

jars i have included are :

1. appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.34.jar
2. appengine-api-labs.jar
3. appengine-endpoints-deps.jar appengine-endpoints.jar
4. appengine-jsr107cache-1.9.34.jar asm-4.0.jar
5. datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar
6. datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar
7. jta-1.1.jar

how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use Maven and import the [App Engine Client For Google Cloud Storage](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.tools/appengine-gcs-client). If Maven is not an option, here is a screenshot of what Maven downloaded for me:

[image]

Comment: Added all these dependencies under referenced libraries ,still no luck. Please suggest.

Comment: Are you sure you used the right version of the jars? The best way really is to use Maven though, as it handles all dependencies for you. If you don't know Maven, there are plenty of tutorials on the web.